# python: MYSQLdb. how to get columns name without executing select * in a big table?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to get the column names of a table, but there a over million data in it.
So I cannot use:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
print cursor.description
```

And in sqlite3, I do it this way

```
crs.execute("PRAGMA table_info(%s)" %(tablename[0]))
for info in crs:
    print info
```

But this is not working in python mysqldb. Any one know how to do that?

Comment: `show columns from <table name>`;

Comment: Then you deserve an upvote.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`SHOW columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html):

```
cursor.execute("SHOW columns FROM table_name")
print [column[0] for column in cursor.fetchall()]
```

FYI, this is essentially the same as using [`desc`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html):

```
cursor.execute("desc table_name")
print [column[0] for column in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: It is `column[0]`, not `columns[0]`. I am unable to edit the code because the edit is less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to do this would be to use `"SHOW columns FROM table_name"` however, you could also simply add a `LIMIT` to your existing query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0")
print cursor.description
```

Comment: The benefit of this over "SHOW COLUMNS" or "DESCRIBE" or "SHOW CREATE TABLE" is that you can also use it for fake tables like the results of "SHOW PROCESSLIST"

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1")
```

or

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 1=0")
```

Both prevent massive amounts of data being rattled. The second one is perhaps more elegant.
I've just checked, and even this works:

```
>>>cursor.execute("SELECT LEFT(long_text,5) as short_text FROM table_name WHERE 1=0")
>>>print cursor.description
(('short_text', 253, 0, 5, 5, 31, 0),)
```

Comment: The LIMIT = 1 will return a single row. If you want to return the column headings AND subsequently display a few rows of data, you can iterate over the cursor.description, which is a tuple of tuples, as: print("\t".join([column[0] for column in cursor.description]))

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0")
cursor.column_names
```

Use the following to find other information

```
[v for v in dir(cursor) if v.find("_")]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME'""", conn)
print(data.COLUMN_NAME)
```

After creating the connection, using the information schema, we call pull the column names without extracting any observations.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).