# Why select query returs data as tuple, i need associative array in python

Tags: python, django

I am new in python, I am working on `models.py`, I can see it shows me data as tuple, I need associate array, can anyone please help me for that, Here is my code for that, It shows me output this output `((1, "What's up?", datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 19, 7, 38, 6, 449735))`, i need field value data

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import connection
from django.db import models


class Question():
    @classmethod
    def get_poll_question(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            db_table = "polls_question"
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM '+db_table)
            allquestion = cursor.fetchall()
            return allquestion
```

Comment: Please update your question with examples of the actual output and your desired output.

Comment: i need field value data in json

Comment: You might be able to use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786674/python-mysqldb-how-to-get-columns-name-without-executing-select-in-a-big-tab/33742886

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```py
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

class Question():
    @classmethod
    def get_poll_question(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            db_table = "polls_question"
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM '+db_table)
            allquestion = dictfetchall(cursor)
            return allquestion
```

Comment: @NikulPanchal Be sure to read up on the perils of SQL injection. While your code seems okay with the definition of `db_table`, string substitution in SQL queries with variables is normally a very bad idea. Good luck!